# Background image not visible in simulator

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have created application using jQuery, which has set image for content div.

The image is visible in Safari,
but when I try to run it on Android Simulator,
Background image is not visible...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to write your Android applications on Java.